# Displaying custom message

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to display a custom message box from my custom module called 'xx_project'

The code below is from a class I made that contains the warning. I then want to call this warning from my custom module 'xx_project'

```
class warning(osv.osv_memory):
_name = 'warning'
_description = 'warning'
_columns = {
    'type': fields.selection(WARNING_TYPES, string='Type', readonly=True),
    'title': fields.char(string="Title", size=100, readonly=True),
    'message': fields.text(string="Message", readonly=True),
}
_req_name = 'title'

def _get_view_id(self, cr, uid):
    """Get the view id
    @return: view id, or False if no view found
    """
    res = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid,
                                                              'xx_project', 'warning_form')
    return res and res[1] or False

def message(self, cr, uid, id, context):
    message = self.browse(cr, uid, id)
    message_type = [t[1] for t in WARNING_TYPES if message.type == t[0]][0]
    print '%s: %s' % (_(message_type), _(message.title))
    res = {
        'name': '%s: %s' % (_(message_type), _(message.title)),
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_id': self._get_view_id(cr, uid),
        'res_model': 'warning',
        'domain': [],
        'context': context,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
        'res_id': message.id
    }
    return res

def info(self, cr, uid, title, message, context=None):
    id = self.create(cr, uid, {'title': title, 'message': message, 'type': 'info'})
    res = self.message(cr, uid, id, context)
    return res
```

And then finally in xx_project I have a field named 'xx_message' that calls the function 'get_message'.

get_message looks like this:

```
def get_message(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    return self.pool.get('warning').info(cr, uid, title='Export imformation',
                                         message="%s products Created, %s products Updated " % (
                                         "test", "test"))
```

And 'xx_message':

```
    _columns = {
    'xx_message': fields.function(get_message)
}
```

I keep getting a Keyerror when I try and run this code, any ideas?